# Powershell get-RDUserSession hanging

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-rds, terminal-services

I'm trying to use the cmdlet get-rdusersession with a broker and a collection and it just hangs without giving any output, what could be the reason and what can I do?

I expect to get the user sessions but it's just stuck.